# How to make clean commits with etckeeper?

Tags: git, etckeeper

I would like to make clean commits with etckeeper. Here is what happens:

1) Check the status of the repository :

```
git status

On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

2) Modify a configuration file :

```
vi myfile.conf
```

3) Add it to the index

```
git add myfile.conf
```

4) Make a commit

```
git commit -m"Add this ... to myfile.conf"
```

5) Observe the commit :

```
git log -p -1

[...]
 maybe chmod 0644 'magic.mime'
-maybe chmod 0644 'mail.rc'
 maybe chmod 0644 'mailcap'
 maybe chmod 0644 'mailcap.order'
 maybe chmod 0644 'mailname'
+maybe chmod 0644 'mail.rc'
 maybe chmod 0644 'manpath.config'
 maybe chmod 0644 'matplotlibrc'
 maybe chmod 0755 'maven'
 [...]
 (My modification to myfile.conf)
 [...]
```

I understand that etckeeper need to keep track of file permissions in the git repository even if I don't understand the purpose of this reordering. I would like to separate in distinct commits all modifications related to the `./etckeeper` directory and modifications related to the content of the configuration files.

How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Etckeeper sets up a git hook to commit the file containing metadata information whenever metadata changes. This is usually the right thing. If you really want to bypass the commit hook, you can run `git commit --no-verify`.

The metadata file is sorted by file name. The sorting order depends on the ambient locale. In your case, the file appears to have been sorted in a pure byte lexicographic order (with `mail.rc` before `mailcap` since `.` is before `c` in ASCII), but you are now running git in a locale where sorting is done in a somewhat human-friendly way, with punctuation ignored except as a last resort (probably a UTF-8 locale) (with `mail.rc` after `mailname` since `n` is before `r`). Run `LC_ALL=C git commit` to do the sorting in pure lexicographic order. It would make sence to add `export LC_COLLATE=C` to `/etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf` to force a consistent sorting order.

Comment: You are right metadata and config modifications should be committed together. The noise was coming from the modification of the sort order. Thank you for this!